# Codingbat coverting recursive loop to for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

I am doing codingbat as practice for an upcoming quiz that I have. I am doing the recursion problems using recursion, but my teacher said that I should be able to do them using other loops. I figured that I should use for loops as they achieve are easily able to achieve the same result.

But I am having trouble converting the recursion to a for loop.

This is the problem:

```
Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively the number of times that sub appears in the string, without the sub strings overlapping.

strCount("catcowcat", "cat") → 2

strCount("catcowcat", "cow") → 1

strCount("catcowcat", "dog") → 0
```

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
public int strCount(String str, String sub) {
int number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i >= str.length() - 1; i++) {
  if (str.substring(i, sub.length()).equals(sub)) {
    number += 1;
  }
}

return number;
}
```

When I return, everything returns as 0.

Comment: I don't think your for loop is ever entered. Try changing greater than str.length to less than.

Comment: Wait so are you supposed to use loops or recursion? Codingbat specifically wants recursion...

Comment: @SethKitchen I am supposed to use loops

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop when you say

```
i >= str.length() - 1
```

the loop is never entered, because you are testing that `i` is greater than the allowed length (and it isn't). You need something like

```
i <= str.length() - 1
```

**or**

```
i < str.length()
```

Also, `number += 1;` can be written as `number++;`

Comment: I tried that and it gives me this error for each test:
`Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 (line number:4)`

Comment: Then it's an empty `String`. You could test for that condition with `String.isEmpty()` (but clearly an empty `String` contaitns no substrings).

Answer (score 0):

One of the details you missed is "without the sub strings overlapping".  This problem calls for a while loop, rather than a for loop, since the index will be incremented by different amounts, depending on whether there is a match or not.

Here's executable code to test whether or not the strCount method works correctly.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class StringCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringCount stringCount = new StringCount();
        System.out.println(stringCount.strCount("catcowcat", "cat"));
        System.out.println(stringCount.strCount("catcowcat", "cow"));
        System.out.println(stringCount.strCount("catcowcat", "dog"));
    }

    public int strCount(String str, String sub) {
        int count = 0;
        int length = str.length() - sub.length();
        int index = 0;

        while (index <= length) {
            int substringLength = index + sub.length();
            if (str.substring(index, substringLength).equals(sub)) {
                count++;
                index += sub.length();
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

}
```